# How to stop Open GL renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es

For some reason, I need to restart a GLSurfaceView.Renderer so I want some time in my app to call setRenderer(newRenderer) a second time, which Android doesn't like and throws a IllegalStateException saying "setRenderer has already been called"...

Now, I know this is because the renderer is attached to the GLSurfaceView and I need to unbind this renderer to the surface view, so I can call again setRenderer.

Anyone has a solution for this ?

P.S.:
Code looks like this :

```
render = new Renderer(this);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
graphicView = (GLSurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.graphicView);

//DO STUFF

graphicView.setRenderer(render);

//DO STUFF

Renderer newRender = new Renderer();
graphicView.setRenderer(newRender); <= ...and Android hates this line sooo much
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c2f132eb8a420f54#), this "LemonDev" do saved my life :

One can stop/destroy an OpenGL surface view and set the new GLSurfaceView a new renderer by calling the OnPause() and postDelayed the destruction with a Handler and a Runnable, like this :

```
final Renderer newRender = new GRenderer(this);
final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main);
graphicView.onPause();

Handler handler = new Handler();
class RefreshRunnable implements Runnable{

    public RefreshRunnable(){

    }

    public void run(){
        ll.removeView(findViewById(R.id.graphicView));

        GLSurfaceView surfaceview = new GLSurfaceView(getApplication());
        surfaceview.setId(R.id.graphicView);
        surfaceview.setRenderer(newRender);

        ll.addView(surfaceview);

        graphicView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.graphicView);
    }
};

RefreshRunnable r = new RefreshRunnable(this);
handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
```

This will create a new renderer and pause the GLSurfaceView. The application then will "destroy" some internal stuffs that you can't touch with the SDK... After this, you can destroy the GLSurfaceView, create another one and set the new renderer to it.

My problem now is that the textures are not refreshed yet but, still, this is great !

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to call setRenderer twice?

The [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderer%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer%29) mentions :

> This method should be called once and only once in the life-cycle of a
>   GLSurfaceView.

Instead, I guess you want to pause the rendering?

Use `setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);` to pause the renderer

Comment: Well, there is a memory leak in the app and we've got no time anymore to find the cause (we've looking for this since two weeks). We need to restart the render thread every X seconds so it won't freeze.

Pausing the renderer (ie calling onPause before the second setRenderer) doesn't help and the app still throw this exception when the rendering thread is paused

Comment: As the doc mentions, it is not allowed to call setRenderer twice. You have to find another way to achieve what you want. The only (dirty) way to do this would be to destroy the view and create a new one (and then, call setRenderer for the 2nd time)

Comment: Already done that, boss ! But still getting IllegalStateException. It's just like it doesn't reset the graphicView after `this.graphcView = null; this.graphicView = (GLSurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.graphicView);`

Comment: This won't reset your GLSurface. It just set your local ptr to null and then you get the same view as before. You have to call `this.graphicView = new GLSurfaceView();` and replace the view with id `R.id.graphicView` by this new one. Then you will be able to call setRenderer again

Answer (score 2):

I found an easier way to refresh textures. In your Activity class call invalidate() and then in your surface view class your onDrawFrame will keep getting called everytime..So you can load your texture here and thereby your work will be done!